# Copying objects between s3 buckets on a different endpoint urls

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to copy an object from `s3://open-images-dataset` bucket. I'm able to download it locally using the following command.

```
aws s3 --no-sign-request cp s3://open-images-dataset/tar/train_0.tar.gz ./
```

Above command will download the tar file in my local directory.
From there, I will upload this file to another s3 bucket `mybucket`. That is in-house s3 storage bucket of my organisation. So it requires different set of access key/id and endpoint url to connect and access that bucket. So once the download is done, I have another script that connect to `mybucket` and uploads the downloaded object.

I was wondering, if there is a way to eliminate this hop and directly copy the object from source bucket `s3://open-images-dataset` to `mybucket`. Since I don't have that much of disk space locally and running into space issues. I have tried the following command but of no luck, probably I'm missing something:

```
aws s3 --no-sign-request cp s3://open-images-dataset/tar/train_0.tar.gz s3://mybucket --endpoint-url https://myendpointurl
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you specifying an `--endpoint-url`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this by providing arguments at the end of the command.
Plus if you want to copy all data from bucket1 to bucket2 then use **sync** instead of cp.

```
aws s3 cp s3://dataBucket/test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt --no-sign-request
```

sync:

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2
```